# How to change mountpoint name?

Tags: linux, directory, mount

I am working in ubuntu, this is what df -h shows:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda         30G  1.7G   27G   6% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             15G   12K   15G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.0G  372K  3.0G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             15G     0   15G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/vdb        197G   60M  187G   1% /mnt
```

Now I want to change the name of `/mnt` to `/data` directory instead. I want all the content to stay where it is, the only thing that has to change is the name of the drive mountpoint.

Here is what I have in `/etc/fstab` file.

```
LABEL=c3image-rootfs    /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/vdb        /mnt    auto    defaults,nobootwait,comment=cloudconfig 0       2
```

Could you please explain the commands necessary and the files to edit?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It goes without saying that you should be careful, and understand what each command does before running it - you might also need to make sure that nothing is using the files while you do this.

Make the new mountpoint

```
mkdir /data
```

unmount the current mountpoint

```
umount /mnt
```

edit /etc/fstab and change `/mnt` to `/data`

```
/dev/vdb        /data    auto    defaults,nobootwait,comment=cloudconfig 0       2
```

mount the new location

```
mount /data
```

It is not recommended to remove the /mnt directory because in part of Linux standard system tree, but you can remove the old mount point, named for example /old/mnt/path with this command:

```
rmdir /old/mnt/path
```

because a mount points is a directory.

Answer (score 0):

A little alternative would be renaming /mnt to /data after umount. 
Also it would be better to change the label for it. e.g. for xfs file type:

```
xfs_admin -L "data" /dev/vdb
```

Answer (score 0):

Following things to make sure before changing the mount point.

1. Is there any change in username and group of the mount. if yes make sure service account user and group are created.
2. The mount name folder should exists in the /home/ directory, if not do create an empty folder with the same name you wanted the mount to be.
3. Verify the /home/ mount folder user:group are correct.
4. Now use ***umount*** command to unmount the mount you wanted.
5. use ***mount*** command to mount the file system you wanted to rename.